# NPM install fails on ubuntu 20.04 Vagrant box

Tags: nodejs, npm, vagrant

I'm running into ENOENT errors when trying to npm install on a Linux Vagrant box. My code in the provisioning script looks like:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
cd <directory with package.json> && npm install
```

Error output is:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-58-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
```

I'm fairly new to Vagrant, but this looks to me like something is broken in npm, rather than the package.json?

Comment: As this issue isn't Ubuntu specific, you'll probably get better support on an NPM site.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, the solution here
https://www.speich.net/articles/en/2018/12/24/virtualbox-6-how-to-enable-symlinks-in-a-linux-guest-os/
is supposed to fix it. But I didn't find that to work. I did leave that enabled.

What I did was:

- remove `node_modules` completely
- create a directory in the guest `~/node_modules`
- `cd my-project-dir; ln -s ~/node_modules` .
- `npm install`

At that point, it worked fine. In spite of how the "setextradata" is supposed ot work, it seems to be still an issue with creating symlinks in the host synced directory.